# makefile problem

Tags: java, makefile

Hello I have a problem while trying to run a makefile.

I change the path where my java install folder is(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin), but when I try to run 'make' from my command line I receive : 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I need to use makefiles for my current application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run make from the directory it resides in, or add it to your path (press Windows key + Pause/Break > Advanced > Environment Variables > find path under "System variables")

If you don't have make, download it from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). Or maybe you do have it and just need to search your hard drive for make.exe

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't had any make on my hard drive.
Thank you for your answers guys.
I downloaded it now and hopefully will serve me well.